# DOM not updating after data changes in vue.js

Tags: ajax, dom, vuejs2

so I'm using vue.js to render in the DOM a list of items i'm fetching from a server using an AJAX call and then I loop through a template in my html to print the labels of these items. But the problem is that after successfully fetching the data AND adding it to the array the DOM doesn't update with the new items. Here's the js code :

```
$(".wrench").click(function () 
{
lastClickedWrench = $(this).attr('id');
console.log("uri :" + lastClickedWrench);
var renderToolbox = new Vue({

    el: "#renderToolbox",
    data: function()
    {
        return {
            listOfStuff: []
        }
        
    },

    mounted: function()
    {
        var vueInstance = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/roles/' + lastClickedWrench,

            success: function(responseData)
            {
                for(let i = 0; i<responseData.length; i++)
                {
                    vueInstance.$set(vueInstance.listOfStuff, i, responseData[i].label);
                    //vueInstance.listOfStuff.splice(i, 1, responseData[i])
                }
                //vueInstance.listOfStuff = responseData;
                console.log(vueInstance.listOfStuff);  // this gives me the correct list
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                console.log('error', error);
                alert("error" + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
    });
});
```

All the commented out lines are solutions I tried from old stackoverflow posts which don't seem to work for me.
Here's the html template :

```
<div id="renderToolbox">
     <template v-for="item in listOfStuff">
         <li class="dd-item" data-id="null">
            <div class="dd-handle">
                <span> {{item}} </span>
            </div>
          </li>
     </template>
</div>
```

I also know about the caveat about the v-for directive which is mentioned in the documentation here : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

I really tried everything, but nothing seems to work. Would appreciate any input on my problem.

Comment: can you try `vueInstance.forceUpdate()` after your for loop

Comment: @VAMSIKRISHNA I tried `vueInstance.$forceUpdate();`  it still doesn't update my DOM :/

Comment: Your code works. Here's a working fiddle that you can compare with to see what's different. https://jsfiddle.net/yw130euo/1/

Comment: The code works yes, but the problem is the DOM not being updated after the data in the list changes, but I actually found the solution and I'll post it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was basically I created a new Vue for every click. The solution is to simply create the Vue once on document load.

```
 var renderToolboxVue = new Vue({
    el: "#renderToolbox",

    data:
    {
        listOfSkills: null
    },

    methods:
     {
        fetchData: function()
        {
            var vueInstance = this;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',

                url: '/ascSkill/' + lastClickedWrench + '?company=' + getQueryParam("company") + '&lang=' + getQueryParam("lang"),

                success: function(responseData)
                {
                    vueInstance.listOfSkills = responseData;
                },
                error: function(error)
                {
                    console.log('error', error);
                    alert("error" + JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        }
     }
});
```

and have the method fetchData() that we created to be called on click like this :

```
 $('.wrench').click(function()
 { 
     renderToolboxVue.fetchData(); 
 });
```

This will allow the Vue to update accordingly with the data passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
vueInstance.$set(vueInstance.listOfStuff, i, responseData[i].label);
```

with:

```
this.listOfStuff.push({i:responseData[i].label})
```

Comment: pushing data to the existing one is not the behavior I need but I tried it anyway and it still didn't update my DOM which is really weird considering in the documentation they say that Vue.js watches for this method and updates.

Comment: https://codepen.io/mahila_5088/pen/VWvrEP   
See this link for working code I guess you din included jqerymin.js

Comment: Really thank you for trying to help, but it's like nobody even reads the question. If I didn't add Jquery would the ajax call even work with the code I had ? No. The problem I had was that even though I have the right data ie : in  `console.log(vueInstance.listOfStuff);` and the data changed accordingly, it didn't update in the dom, the DOM. I will post a detailed solution to the problem later.